# React js, error about keys when map on array

Tags: reactjs

I have an Array. I'm using map to show it in `React`. React throw me error about  keys, I don't know why. Any ideas why is `React` throw this error?

```
{
    this.state.buttons.map((button, index) => {
       return (
       <>
         {index % 4 === 0 && (
           <div key={`break-${index}`} className="w-100" />
         )}
         <Button key={index} char={button} click={this.pushString} />
       </>
     )
})}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that you passed your index to your `div`, which isn't the top-level component returned in your `map()` - your `<>` (React Fragment) is.

The quick-fix here would be to give it the key. However, since the short syntax doesn't support any attributes, you need to use the longer, explicit syntax to declare keys there:

```
<React.Fragment key={index}>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{this.state.buttons.map((button, index) => {
               return (
               <div key={index}>
                 {index % 4 === 0 && (
                   <div  className="w-100" />
                 )}
                 <Button char={button} click={this.pushString} />
               <div/>
             )
           })}
```

Keys need to be unique. Pass index as key

Comment: I cant do it, bootstrap cry when I do.

Comment: Nothing, but layout is broken :/

Comment: @ŁukaszKlejszta, maybe it broke because of the div's in this answer that you didn't have before?